# Pyomo: How to modify the value of a variable and see the changes that it makes in other variables?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pyomo, glpk

I have a pyomo model with some variables and constraints. These variables are connected by the constraints. For understanding the model and solution better I've put a breakpoint right after I solve the model using glpk solver.

My requirement now is that, I want to modify the value of one or more variables in the debug console and see the effect that it has on other variables.

How to do this with pyomo?

Simply doing `om.variable1.set_value(35)` or `om.variable1 = 35` only sets the variable to 35. But it doesn't seem to modify other variables and the constraints are not satisfied.

Comment: See section `Fixing Variables and Re-solving` in https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_models.html